# Attribute application@label is also present at

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, android-manifest

After installing a new library in my android project, I get the following error:

```
/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    Attribute application@label value=(Compassion) from (unknown)
    is also present at [com.github.master] AndroidManifest.xml:15:9-41 value=(@string/app_name).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:6:4-36:19 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some research, I found that the newly installed library also has a `application@label` attribute, so all you have to do is modify your `AndroidManifest.xml` file by adding the following two lines of code:

1. Add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to the manifest tag

```xml
<manifest
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
...
```

2. Add `tools:replace="android:label"` to the application tag

```xml
...
   <application
        tools:replace="android:label">
```

Answer (score 5):

Go to main AndroidManifest.xml and paste these two lines below

In manifest tag

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

And in the Application tag

```
tools:replace="android:label"
```

This work for me

Answer (score 1):

You can add this line in Manifest application tag

```
tools:replace="android:name"
```

and if you are using androidx use this line in gradle proprieties

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```